# Solving Differential Equation $y'=\sin(y-x-1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm stucked with sovling this equation.

$$y'=\sin(y-x-1)$$

I know I have to use change of variables e.g.  $z=y-x-1$ and $z'=y'-1$ but then I am not getting anywhere

Comment: What equation are you getting for $z(x)$?

Comment: this equation --> $z'+1=sin(z)$

Comment: I guess you have learned at some point the method of separation in order to solve a differential equation. Try to apply it to this case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the substitution $z = y-x-1$, you get:
$$y' = \sin(y-x-1) \Rightarrow z' = \sin(z) - 1$$

This is separable, hence:

$$\frac{dz}{\sin(z) - 1} = dx \Rightarrow \\
\frac{2}{\tan\left(\frac{z}{2}\right) - 1} = x + c \Rightarrow \\
\tan\left(\frac{z}{2}\right) = \frac{2+x+c}{x+c} \Rightarrow \\
z(x) = 2\arctan\left[\frac{2+x+c}{x+c}\right].$$

Then:

$$y(x) = z(x) + x + 1 = x+ 1 + 2\arctan\left[\frac{2+x+c}{x+c}\right]$$

Comment: wouldn't it be $z'+1=sin(z)$ ???

Comment: @NavidAgz yeah, you're right. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

setting $$u=y-x-1$$ then we get $$y'=u'+1$$ and our equation is $$u'+1=\sin(u)$$
solving this equation we get $$u \left( x \right) =2\,\arctan \left( {\frac {{\it \_C1}+x+2}{{\it 
\_C1}+x}} \right) 
$$